# write arabic in excel from datatable asp.net

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to write data to excel file from a database but I got a problem with the word in arabic:

its look like : `Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø¨Øª`

I tried this code :

```
Application.Lock();
        SqlConnection con = Connection.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT u.* FROM sarcshiftuser AS u WHERE (table_id =  (SELECT TOP (1) table_id FROM sarcshifttable ORDER BY table_id DESC)) ",con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable usertable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(usertable);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=Employee.xls";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",  attachment );

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";


Response.Write("السبت"); // in this row I tried to write saturday word in arabic but its appear :`Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø¨Øª`
Response.End();
        Application.UnLock();
```

any help ? 
another question if it possible : 
how can I merge cells and color the background of the cell from c# code behind ?

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: This will after this line this line  ==>> HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

Comment: Please edit your answer and format it properly instead of writing this in comments.